# How to use concat function without losing superscript in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have a statistical analised data, which I have to concat a number plus its superscripts.
like:

99.5     A

105.2    B

45.6     AB

So, the letters are superscript. When I use concat function they lose formating and come back to normal letters.

Is there anyway to automat this?

Thanks.

Comment: Through VBA yes, otherwise I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula to replace the characters with their unicode value for superscripts:

`=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,A1:A2),"A",UNICHAR(7468)),"B",UNICHAR(7470))`

If you have more characters than a mapping table might be helpful.

Comment: Yeah, I have the alphabet so I dont think this solution would be very usefull

Comment: As you can't format individual characters within in a formula result, the only way would be to transform the result of the formula to a value and then check for non-numeric characters and set their `font.superscript = true`